# How to show an element within a div if I only have a class?

Tags: jquery, function, hover

I have the following code:

```
$('.my-image').function(){
   $(this + ' div').show();
},
function(){
   $(this + ' div').hide();
});
```

I know it's not working, because I request an object with a div, but I don't know how I should be more explicit.

```
<div id='galery'>
   <div class='my-image'><div></div></div>
   <div class='my-image'><div></div></div>
</div>
```

How should I call the jquery function to show the inner div (child div)?

Comment: it's not working because jQuery doesn't have a function called `function` did you make a copy-paste error?

Comment: I think he is missing a function like `hover`... guessing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this + ' div').show();
```

should be

```
$(this).find("div").show();
```

or

```
$("div", this).show()
```

`this` is an object, not a string.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a DOM element; you cannot concatenate it into a selector.

You're trying to write

```
$(this).find('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with children:

```
$('.my-image').function(){
   $(this).children('div').show();
},
function(){
   $(this).children('div').hide();
});
```